# Why does app close when asking for permissions? java

Tags: java, android

I have code that asks the user for camera permission and then will take the picture. However when I click the take-picture button, the app closes and then the dialog comes up. When I select an option and then click to go back to the app, it works. Is there any reason for this or any way to fix it?

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);

        takePicture = v.findViewById(R.id.openCamera);
        imageIv = v.findViewById(R.id.imageIv);

        takePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkPermissionAndOpenCamera();
            }
        });


        return v;
    }


    private void checkPermissionAndOpenCamera() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, storageRequestCode);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, cameraRequestCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (cameraRequestCode == 100) {
            Bitmap capturedImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageIv.setImageBitmap(capturedImage);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (storageRequestCode == 101) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                checkPermissionAndOpenCamera();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need any permissions to use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Why are you requesting any permissions at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return after `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` line.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, storageRequestCode);
    return;
}
```

You didn't return there so it will request permission and start the camera at the same time.

And like @ianhanniballake mentioned: `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent doesn't needed your app to request permission.